# How do I get the SUM of a group in an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM acodes
WHERE datenumber >=  '2016-12-09'
GROUP BY campaignid, acode
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Results are

[image: sql results]

Is there a way to SUM() the `maxworth` column? I want to add up all the `maxworth` shown above in an sql query. The answer is not `SELECT *, SUM(maxworth)` as there are multiple `maxworth` for the same `acode` and `campaignid`.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking, but I think you should checkout the ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS keywords

Comment: @desbest Can you please explain " sum the numbers of  another column ?"

Comment: @Lioness It means I want the sum of the `maxworth` column shown in the image above right after doing the sum sql query shown above.

Comment: I've updated my question @erikkallen

Comment: I've updated my question @Lioness

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the existing query as an inline view. Take the existing query, and wrap in parens, and then use that in place of a table name in another query. (The inline view will need to be assigned an alias.)

For example:

```
SELECT SUM(v.maxworth)
  FROM (
         -- existing query goes here, between the parens
         SELECT *
         FROM acodes
         WHERE datenumber >=  '2016-12-09'
         GROUP BY campaignid, acode
         LIMIT 0 , 30
       ) v
```

In MySQL, that inline view is referred to as a *derived table*. The way that query works.... MySQL first runs the query in the inline view, and materializes the resultset into a derived table. Once the derived table is populated, the outer query runs against that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking here.

```
SELECT
    a.MAXWORTH1,
    SUM(a.MAXWORTH) AS "MAXWORTH2"
FROM (
    SELECT 
      CAMPAIGNID, 
      SUM(maxworth) AS "MAXWORTH1"
    FROM acodes 
    WHERE datenumber ='2016-12-05' 
    GROUP BY campaignid 
) a
GROUP BY a.MAXWORTH1
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Unknown column 'a.MAXWORTH' in 'field list'

Comment: Maybe try with alias in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This calculates the SUM() by unique campaignid, acode, and maxworth. You mention "there are multiple maxworth for the same acode and campaignid" which makes me think you might be wanting to treat "maxworth" as unique.

```
    SELECT 
      campaignid,
      acode,
      maxworth,
      SUM(maxworth) AS 'MAXWORTH1'
    FROM acodes 
    WHERE datenumber >= '2016-12-09' 
    GROUP BY campaignid, acode, maxworth
```

Comment: Sorry but you do not understand my question. Each row has a `amountpaid` and `maxworth` and is grouped by `campaignid` and `acode`. There are multiple rows with the same `campaignid` and `acode` which have the same `maxworth` What you are doing, is adding up every row where `campaignid` and `acode` matches, so it is adding up the same `maxworth` multiple times. This is now what I want to do. I want to do a query that groups the rows by`campaignid` and `acode` as my original query, does but add up all the rows in the resulting `maxworth` column. http://i.imgur.com/ARlBa5v.png

Comment: Draw a picture of what you want it to look like when you're done.

Comment: What's there not to understand? I want to modify this sql query to add up (get the sum) everything in the `maxworth` column. `SELECT *
FROM acodes
WHERE datenumber >=  '2016-12-09'
GROUP BY campaignid, acode
LIMIT 0 , 30` The answer is not `SELECT * , SUM(maxworth)
FROM acodes
WHERE datenumber >=  '2016-12-09'
GROUP BY campaignid, acode
LIMIT 0 , 30`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt at answering your question.

```
SELECT
    a.campaignid,
    a.acode,
    SUM(a.maxworth) as "SUMMAXWORTH"
FROM
    (SELECT 
        * 
    FROM acodes 
    WHERE datenumber >= '2016-12-09' 
    GROUP BY campaignid, acode 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
    ) a
GROUP BY a.campaignid, a.acodes
```

Comment: This means the column name is not correct. There is no 's' in the column name so changing it to 'a.acode' will solve the error.

Comment: FUNCTION a.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: oops it actually SUM(a.maxworth)